# Unable to read less than 1024 bytes (1KB) with fread in PHP

Tags: php, put, fread

I want to read a file in PUT request. As suggested in the PHP documentation:

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

But when the file sent is less than 1 KB, then it doesnt read. Do anyone know about this specific behaviour of fread in PHP?
Thanks!

Even when the while condition is changed to 
`while($data=fread($putdata, 512))`, it doesn't go inside the loop. I don't know its specific behaviour, but is it like that fread doesn't support a chunk less than 1024? Just curious!

Comment: the loop will break if data equals exactly 0, if you try to read and it only reads the letter 0, $data will be parsed as false and breaks, this is the only reason comes to my mind

Comment: Yes, that I agree. But when I edit that condition like while($data=fread($putdata, 512)), then it just doesn't go inside that loop. Apologies for incomplete information.

Comment: I really can't reproduce the error.  But maybe try `while (!feof($putdata)) { $data = fread($putdata, 1024); fwrite($fp, $data); }`

Comment: @TimDev: Same output, nothing goes into $data.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use [`stream_copy_to_stream()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php) than manually copying 1KB at a time?

Comment: but why are you trying to read only 1kb each time?  maybe we can find a solution to that

Comment: @Anonymous stream_copy_to_stream() is returning FALSE in this case.

Comment: @DanielKrom I am trying for lesser value, but it is not working for values less than 1 kb. And the files in request will presumably never go beyond 1kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stream_get_contents($fp) worked! It returned the contents of an already open stream ($fp in this case) as a string in one shot.
Thank you all for your suggestions :)